# Failed to instantiate module, Even when proper module defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="../angular/angular-1.6.7/angular.js"/>
    <script src="../angular/angular-1.6.7/angular-route.min.js"/>
    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="../modules/familyTree.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../controllers/mainController.js"/ -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var test= angular.module("myTest", []);
        test.controller("main", ["$scope",function ($scope) {
            $scope.headline = "Its Started";
        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myTest">
<div ng-controller="main">
    <h1>{{headline}}</h1>
    {{1+2}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Wrote this code could not figure out whats wrong with it.

Please help, Continuously getting the error.

Thanks in advance.

```
angular.js:116 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.7/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp
    at file:///D:/src/main/resources/templates/angular/angular-1.6.7/angular.js:116:12
    at file:///D:/src/main/resources/templates/angular/angular-1.6.7/angular.js:2303:17
    at ensure (file:///D:/src/main/resources/templates/angular/angular-1.6.7/angular.js:2224:38)
```

Comment: why error is saying *failed to instantiate `myApp` module* missing, even though you used `ng-app="myTest"` on page? Also script tags aren't closed correctly..

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the script tags for all the references,

Change

From

```
 <script src="../angular/angular-1.6.7/angular.js"/>
 <script src="../angular/angular-1.6.7/angular-route.min.js"/>
```

To

```
 <script src="../angular/angular-1.6.7/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="../angular/angular-1.6.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

**DEMO**

```js
 var test= angular.module("myTest", []);
  test.controller("main", ["$scope",function ($scope) {
  $scope.headline = "Its Started";
 }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body ng-app="myTest">
<div ng-controller="main">
    <h1>{{headline}}</h1>
    {{1+2}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah! OP only knows :_

Comment: Yes, Works like magic.
Any particular reason why this happened.?

Comment: I have mentioned that you have not closed the script properly , Mark if the answer helped